# collapsing toolbar showing an extra toolbar in collapsed state in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am using fragments and in my home fragment i have used a collapsing toolbar; but when it is collapsed it is showing an extra toolbar in above it; i have inflated menu item in the toolbar which i have used inside the collapsing toolbar;
[this is what expanded state looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F6HR.png)

[this is what collapsed state looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrqcT.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/shoppingwomen"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and the java file

```
  public class home__fragment extends  Fragment {
   View root;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        MainActivity.actionBar.hide();
       CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
       collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.action_search:
                                {  item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

                                    final androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) item.getActionView();
                                    searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color =#999999>Search Product</font>"));
                                    searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(225, 225, 225));

                                    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductList.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("search", query);
                                            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;}
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

please help me out how can i get rid of the toolbar that appears in the collapsed state

Comment: Would you please add the Activity layout to the question too?